# Entity Framework - TOP using a dynamic query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm having issues implementing the TOP or SKIP functionality when building a new object query.

I can't use eSQL because i need to use an "IN" command - which could get quite complex if I loop over the IN and add them all as "OR" parameters.

Code is below :

```
Using dbcontext As New DB

       Dim r As New ObjectQuery(Of recipient)("recipients", dbcontext)
        r.Include("jobs")
        r.Include("applications")

        r = r.Where(Function(w) searchAppIds.Contains(w.job.application_id))

        If Not statuses.Count = 0 Then
            r = r.Where(Function(w) statuses.Contains(w.status))
        End If

           If Not dtFrom.DbSelectedDate Is Nothing Then
                r = r.Where(Function(w) w.job.create_time >= dtDocFrom.DbSelectedDate)

            End If

            If Not dtTo.DbSelectedDate Is Nothing Then
                r = r.Where(Function(w) w.job.create_time <= dtDocTo.DbSelectedDate)

            End If

            'a lot more IF conditions to add in additional predicates

            grdResults.DataSource = r

        grdResults.DataBind()
```

If I use any form of .Top or .Skip it throws an error : Query builder methods are not supported for LINQ to Entities queries

Is there any way to specify TOP or Limit using this method? I'd like to avoid a query returning 1000's of records if possible. (it's for a user search screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than

`r = new ObjectQuery<recipient>("recipients", dbContext)`

try

`r = dbContext.recipients`.

`.Skip()` and `.Take()` return `IOrderedQueriable<T>` while `.Where` returns `IQueriable<T>`.  Thus put the `.Skip()` and `.Take()` last.

Also change `grdResults.DataSource = r` to `grdResults.DataSource = r.ToList()` to execute the query now.  That'll also allow you to temporarily wrap this line in try/catch, which may expose a better message about why it's erroring.

Answer (score 0):

Mark this one down to confusion. I should have been using the .Take instead of .Top or .Limit or anything.

my final part is the below and it works :

```
grdResults = r.Take(100)
```